# Are "X vs Y" product comparison questions not constructive?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, close-reasons

The comparison of two distinct products with similar purposes, as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/451943/virtualbox-versus-vmware), seems to be the sort of question that solicits opinion and therefore not constructive.  However, these questions are not shopping recommendations as they do not ask for a specific product to be recommended.  Should these questions be closed as *not constructive*?

Comment: I agree that "X vs Y" questions are non-constructive. The answer given shows that: "VMware is generally more solid and reliable."

Comment: Unfortunately these questions (in my opinion) are actually super useful to people.  It's a shame SE disdains them...

Comment: There are exceptions: http://superuser.com/questions/439470/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-8-and-windows-rt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, these should be closed as *primarily opinion based*, because they're subjective and there's no real problem to be solved.

A couple of reasons:

- It's easy enough to take a look at what both tools offer online and compare them yourself, with regards to whatever criteria may be more important to you (which could be anything). Answers would simply be a list of features. We don't do feature comparisons – if the OP can't do the comparison themselves, then the problem is possibly hidden behind the question and they should probably just ask about their real issue instead.
- It encourages subjective answers that are merely of the form "I like *X* better than *Y*", simply *because*. It attracts answers very fast because everyone seems to have an opinion, at least about popular software, and it's a magnet for personal opinion without any references to back it up.
- These questions get outdated very fast, since features might change, support for certain operating systems might change, et cetera.

Comment: What if you already did your best to research and you still can't figure out the differences or which is better between two products?

Comment: Because that's the situation I'm in and I don't know which site—if any—is appropriate to ask on...

Comment: Then you need to share that research and try to ask constructively – in what way does a certain product allow you to accomplish something in less time, with fewer steps, et cetera.